# Difference in mass shown on balance and real mass

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

> Milk of density $1000\ \mathrm{kg\ m^{-3}}$ is poured at a steady rate of $0.1\ \mathrm{kg\ s^{-1}}$ into a measuring bowl on top of some accurate scales (measuring the force converted into a mass) from a height of $10\ \mathrm{cm}$. If the pourer stops at the moment the scale read $1\ \mathrm{kg}$, determine the actual mass of milk in the bowl. You may assume that the flow is inviscid and there is no splash up of the liquid.

My work:

Net force = rate of change in momentum
$$F = mu_2 - mu_1$$ 
$$F = 0.1(1.400714-0)$$
$$\text{Net force} = 0.1400714 $$
Time taken to fall :

$$s = ut +0.5at^2$$
$$h = 0.5gt^2$$
$$t^2= \frac{2(0.1)}{9.81}$$
$$t = 0.14278$$
 Force due total mass (shown) = Weight of the milk in bowl + Force due to jet on bowl

$$1(9.81) = mg + 0.1400714 $$
$$\frac{9.81-0.1400714}{9.81} = m$$
$\text{mass flow rate} = \frac{\text{mass flown}}{\text{time}}$
$$\text{mass flown} = 0.1 (0.14278) = 0.014278$$
$$m = 0.98572156\ \mathrm{kg}$$

This is my solution. However many of my colleagues claim that the mass will be $1\ \mathrm{kg}$ (same as shown on the balance). If so, please explain.

Comment: Are you supposed to consider mass in the bowl at the moment you stop pouring, or the mass in the bowl after the stream which has already left the container joins the rest in the bowl?

Comment: yes, I agree, it is not clear if you must include the column that eventually falls into the bowl

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of ways to interpret this question.

"from a height of $0.1\ \mathrm m$" – presumably this is intended to be "from the top of the liquid surface". This means that as the fluid level rises, so does the height of the orifice from which you pour.

"Stops when the scale reads …" – you stop the jet at the time the scales read this value – then there is a column of liquid that still needs to make it into the bowl.

Superficially, they want you to correct for the reaction force due to the liquid that was falling $0.1\ \mathrm m$. If you have $0.1\ \mathrm{kg/s}$ mass flow, dropping $10\ \mathrm{cm}$, then the velocity it has is

$$\begin{align}
v = \sqrt{2 g h} = 1.40\ \mathrm{m/s}\\
F\,\Delta t = m\,\Delta v\\
F = 0.1 \times 1.40 = 0.14\ \mathrm N
\end{align}$$

Now we have the liquid column that still needs to drop – so we need the time to drop. This time is $\sqrt{\frac{2h}{g}} = 0.143\ \mathrm s$ so the additional mass flow is

$$\Delta m = 0.143\ \mathrm s \times 0.1\ \mathrm{kg/s} = 0.0143\ \mathrm{kg} = 0.14\ \mathrm N$$

The two terms exactly cancel out – your friends were right.

It seems to me that in your attempted solution, you were mixing the units between $\mathrm N$ and $\mathrm{kg}$, and this is how you got into trouble. Writing everything in units of mass and mass flow rate $\rho$ only, I get

Part 1 – missing mass:

$$m = \rho \frac{\sqrt{2 g h}}{g} = \rho \sqrt{\frac{2h}{g}}$$

Part 2 – mass in column:

$$m = \rho t = \rho \sqrt{\frac{2h}{g}}$$

And since these have opposite sign, they cancel out exactly.